# clicking on any navigation item it not remain selected

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu and when i click on any menu its background as of home item does not remain selected i tried my best and also did googling but could not solve
my navigation menu is as

```
enter code here

 <ul id="navigation">
            <li id="selected" style="width: 90px"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hov" style="width: 130px"><a href="Help.aspx">Get Help</a></li>
            <li class="hov" style="width: 90px"><a href="Price.aspx">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="hov" style="width: 90px"><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="hov"><a class="hov" href="Disclaimer.aspx">Disclaimer</a></li>
        </ul>
enter code here
```

and its CSS is as:

```
#navigation
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
float: right;
width: 570px;
border: 0px solid red;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: -30px;
}
#navigation li
{
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 40px;
margin-left: 3px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-top: 0px;
border: 0px solid black;
position: relative;
border: 0px solid black;
display: block;
}
.hov a
{
color: black;
}

#navigation li a
{
border: 0px solid black;
height: 30px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#selected a
{
background-color: #097Abf;
color: White;
}
#selected a:hover
{
background-color: #216894;
color: White;
}
.hov a:hover
{
color:  #097Abf;
background: url('supimages/field-bg.gif') repeat-x scroll 0px bottom #FFF;
}
```

Comment: What you have to do is use a javascript function that changes your button id. You will notice that one of the buttons has an `id="selected"`. When you click on one of the other buttons, use javascript to remove the id of the current "selected" button and move it to the newly "selected" button.

Comment: thanks plz can you provide me link also to the script

Comment: Mike's answer does exactly what I described.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed one or two things to show you my approach, should be fairly simple for you to understand this as you got this far.

I added a class of `.active` (your old selected)

```
#navigation a.active
{
background-color: #097Abf;
color: White;
}
```

And I added the following Jquery to add and remove that class from the link when you click on it.

```
   $("#navigation a").click(function(){
    $("#navigation a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

[HERE IS A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc3jY/)

Comment: It might be better if you used IDs instead of classes as that is what the asker was using.